# Select vimenter autocmd's to run based on args

Tags: bash, vim, vimrc

I'm trying to reduce the number of things I need to do when I open VIM.  I have the three following scenarios that I'd like to account for:

### 1. Open vim with a directory specified

`vim .`

For this case, I would like to open NERDTree, with this in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd vimenter * NERDTree
```

### 2. Open vim with a directory specified, on a large monitor

`vim . --large`

Here I'd like to open NERDTree as well as do some screen splits:

```
autocmd vimenter * NERDTree
autocmd vimenter * wincmd w
autocmd vimenter * wincmd v
autocmd vimenter * wincmd v
```

### 3. Open vim with a specific filename

`vim ~/vimrc`

For this case, I would like to not run any of the `autocmd`s that I mentioned above.

### Edit - Final implementation

Thanks to FDinoff's answer.

```
if argc() == 1 && arv(0) == '.' " `vim .` called
  autocmd vimenter * NERDTree   " Start up NERDTree
  autocmd vimenter * wincmd w   " Jump to split that file is open in

  if !empty($L)
    autocmd vimenter * wincmd v
    autocmd vimenter * wincmd v
  endif
endif
```

and run it with `L=t vim .`, `vim .`, or `vim specific_file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`argc()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#argc()) and [`argv()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#argv()) to find the arguments to vim in your vimrc and set the autocmds accordingly. So for the first one you could do something like this to only open NERDTree if the first argument is `.`

```
if argc() == 1 && argv(0) == '.'
    autocmd vimenter * NERDTree
endif
```

For the large monitor I think using the shell variable would be the correct way to do this because vim thinks that `--large` in `vim --large` is an argument to vim not to your script. I do not know if there is a way around this.

You could do something like `vim -- . --large` but then vim opens a buffer for a file `--large` which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm updating the question with my final implementation.

Comment: @RyanB You can also just define `L` in your bashrc so you don't have to type it every time.